# Electric Torque Equation of DFIG Wind Turbine

Tags: power, power-electronics, electric-machine, windturbine

I go through the several books and research paper related with DFIG wind Turbine. There is some confusion regarding these two equations. Can any one clarifies this confusion?

In one place Te = Kopt * wr^2 where Kopt = 0.73; wr- rotor speed.

In other place Te = (e_prime_qs * iqs + e_prime_ds * ids )/ws  where e_prime_qs, e_prime_ds, iqs, ids are stator q and d axis internal voltages and currents and ws is the synchronous speed.

My question is in which situation both equations are equal or they representing some different thing? If I only talk about Wind Turbine then we used Te = Kopt * wr^2  and if we talk about DFIG wind turbine modelling then we talk about later equation Te = (e_prime_qs * iqs + e_prime_ds * ids )/ws.

Please any one clarifies this things. Thank you.

Comment: Something as this : formulas 19-20 http://www.wseas.us/e-library/transactions/systems/2008/26-164.pdf Perhaps this could also help https://journals.ekb.eg/article_114703_2699a287847314b65af6cfbf11860703.pdf

Comment: And this https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/2099.1/18983/1/MainTesis.pdf

Comment: In my opinion  Te = Kopt * wr^2 where Kopt = 0.73; wr- rotor speed, is used for MPPT condition.  On the other side  Te = (e_prime_qs * iqs + e_prime_ds * ids )/ws is use in normal form. Am I right?